# How to listen to modifications of the contents of an SWT List?

Tags: eclipse, swt

I tried using a listener for SWT.Modify event.  This works for Text but seems not to work for List.    That is, the following does not work:

```
    myList = new List(listComp, SWT.MULTI|SWT.BORDER|SWT.V_SCROLL);
    myList.addListener(SWT.Modify, new Listener() {
        public void handleEvent(Event e) {
            System.out.println("My list modified");
            dirty=true;
            }
        });
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Listen to the `SWT.Selection` event instead of `SWT.Modify`.

Consider also to use a [ListViewer](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fviewers%2FListViewer.html) instead of a List, which has `addSelectionChangedListener()` and `addPostSelectionChangedListener()` methods (the later is used be notified when user 'stops' on an item when navigating in the list with keyboard, instead of notifying on each item).

Comment: Thanks, but...  I am not interested in "selection".  The list is changed from the code using "add" and "remove".  There is no user selection involved.

Comment: If it's your code which is adding elements to the list: you should manage your own list of listeners and notify them. You could use the listeners of the List and notify them with `myList.notifyListeners(SWT.Modify, null)` (this doesn't interfere with List behavior because List does not use the event Modify), but it's a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

You should register listeners to your model which is visualized with the list and listen for changes there instead of the widget.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create your own custom list (check e.g. http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/11489/Custom-SWT-List-Box) and directly manage events from within your class?